# Can a sikh girl marry a muslim man if she converts?

Tags: nikah, fiqh

Can a sikh girl marry a muslim man if she converts? what is the ruling behind this?

Comment: Why wouldn't she be able to?

Comment: In general, Islam treats anything as permitted unless there's a reason to forbid it: You've indicated here (a) no reason that this would be forbidden, and (b) no reason to even *expect* a reason for this to be forbidden.  Please see relevant meta discussion here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/663/22

Answer (score 4):

If the girl has become muslim then there is no problem if she marry a muslim man.

Answer (score 2):

there is no problem if she marries him, but she should make sure that she has become a muslim for the sake of Allah, and not simply to get married, as later on in their relationship, things wont work out if they both have different views and beliefs, and raising the children will be a problem. May Allah guide us all to the straight path, Amen